# When preparing new array from existing it appends only last element JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, google-apps-script

I have array what looks like this:

```
var arr = [{name: 'Test', id: 1}, {name: 'Test', id: 2}, {name: 'Test', id: 3}];
```

When I looping through this array I want to prepare new array:

```
var new_arr = [];
for (var key in arr) {
    if (arr[key].name == 'Test') {
        new_arr.push(arr[key]);
    }
}
```

But when I `Logger.log(new_arr)` it looks:

```
[{name: 'Test': id: 3}]
```

So the questions is: What is wrong with this code!? When I log each item all fine, but it looks like it push only last element. Thanks!

P.S. I tested this code on local machine and all works fine!

Comment: Are you sure you're loggin at the right time? Here it's working just fine.

Comment: [Don't use `for…in` enumerations on arrays!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/500504/1048572) (unlikely to be the problem though)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works perfectly in the Google Script editor too...

**code :**

```
function test(){
  var arr = [{name: 'Test', id: 1}, {name: 'Test', id: 2}, {name: 'Test', id: 3}];      
  var new_arr = [];
  for (var key in arr) {
    if (arr[key].name == 'Test') {
      new_arr.push(arr[key]);
    }
  }
  Logger.log(new_arr);
}
```

**result :**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Logger.log() method of the Google Apps Script, you are passing wrong parameters, log() spects an string..

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/logger#log

Try to do this.. and check again:

```
Logger.log(JSON.stringify(new_arr));
```

Comment: If it only has an object beeing passed, it stringify it by default.

Answer (score 0):

When I do a

```
console.debug(new_arr);
```

I get

```
[Object { name="Test",  id=1}, Object { name="Test",  id=2}, Object { name="Test",  id=3}]
```

So your code ist fine. Just the logger seems to be funky.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why it wouldn't work.  As long as you are using `Logger.log` in the correct place.  I did the following and placed `Logger.log` after the `for` loop:

```
function test() {
  var arr = [{
    name: 'Test',
    id: 1
  }, {
    name: 'Test',
    id: 2
  }, {
    name: 'Test',
    id: 3
  }];

  var new_arr = [];

  for (var key in arr) {
    if (arr[key].name == 'Test') {
      new_arr.push(arr[key]);
    }
  }

  Logger.log(new_arr);

}
```

When I look at the log, the result is what you were expecting to see:

> [15-07-31 13:40:31:846 EDT] [{name=Test, id=1.0}, {name=Test, id=2.0}, {name=Test, id=3.0}]

Let me know if I misunderstood your question.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that you run:

```
for(var key in arr)
```

Which is meant for looping over Objects properties.

Use the following for looping over arrays

```
for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) { 
    if (arr[i].name == 'Test') {
        new_arr.push(arr[i]);
    }    
}
```

Or you could use the [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```
var new_arr = arr.filter(function(item){
    return item.name === 'Test'
})
```

Or a while loop, whatever you prefer

Comment: The user actual code is working well, there are a problem with the logger